# RedHat EAP 7.4 missing standalone-ha.xml

Tags: jboss, redhat

I am upgrading from RedHat Jboss EAP 6.4 to 7.4

from this:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-eap-6/eap64-openshift
```

to:

```
FROM registry.redhat.io/jboss-eap-7/eap-74-openjdk8-openshift-rhel8
```

In my Dockerfile i run this command

```
ENV JBOSS_CONFIGURATION=$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration
RUN cp $JBOSS_CONFIGURATION/standalone-ha.xml $JBOSS_CONFIGURATION/standalone.xml
```

The `RUN cp ...` line produces the following error:

```
cp: cannot stat '/opt/eap/standalone/configuration/standalone-ha.xml': No such file or directory
```

Navigating into the filesystem, sure enough the file is missing.

```
[jboss@9975d00f7428 ~]$ cd $JBOSS_HOME
[jboss@9975d00f7428 eap]$ cd ./standalone/configuration/
[jboss@9975d00f7428 configuration]$ ls
application-roles.properties  application-users.properties  logging.properties  mgmt-groups.properties  mgmt-users.properties  standalone-openshift.xml  standalone_xml_history
```

So, where did it go, and how do i get it back?
I tried to see if the file was moved: `cd $JBOSS_HOME; find . -name "satndalone-ha.xml"` but that yielded no results.

I also tried checking the release notes, no help there either.